# Rails delete action is not being run, and renders 200 OK

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I am having trouble implementing the DELETE action on **any** object that I have for my application.

To show you the general code for my delete action in the Group Controller:

```
def destroy
    @group = Group.find(params[:id])
    respond_to do |format|
        if @group.delete
            format.html { redirect_to group_path }
            format.json { head :no_content }
        else
            format.html { redirect_to group_path }
            format.json { head :no_content }
        end
    end
end
```

And the code for my View layout:

```
<h1>My Groups</h1>

  <table>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Users</th>
      <th></th>
      <th></th>
    </tr>

  <% @groups.each do |group| %>
    <tr>
      <td><%= group.name %></td>
      <td>
        <% group.memberships.each do |membership| %>
          <%= User.find(membership.user_id).name %>
          <br/>
        <% end %>
      </td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Show', group %></td>
      <td><%= link_to 'Destroy', group, :confirm => 'Are you sure?', :method => :delete %></td>
    </tr>
  <% end %>
  </table>

  <br />

  <%= link_to 'New Group', new_group_path %>
```

I am unable to delete the group object even though the rails server log gives me back a 200 OK response. The returned page is a blank screen:

```
Started DELETE "/groups/2" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-19 01:22:01 +0800
Processing by GroupsController#destroy as HTML
  Parameters: {"authenticity_token"=>"aH+z0DlL7NeoVlxda8Td76WdnrH7/G8UyWDqbJcTu9w=", "id"=>"2"}
Completed 200 OK in 0ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

ActiveRecord wasn't used and there were no changes to the database. There were no such problems in the past, but I only realized that I could not delete any kind of object recently.

I have been trying to find solutions to similar problems found on the net, but unfortunately it seems like no one has had this problem yet.

**Update 1:**

The following is my application layout:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <%= csrf_meta_tag %>
      <title>Home</title>

        <%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag :application, :media => "all" %>

        <%= javascript_include_tag "/javascripts/main.js" %>
        <%= stylesheet_link_tag "/css/main.css" %>
    </head>
    <body>

        <%= yield %>

    </body>
</html>
```

But when I use the console to delete the object. It works:

```
1.9.3-p194 :003 > Group.find(23).delete
  Group Load (0.5ms)  SELECT "groups".* FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."id" = $1 LIMIT 1  [["id", 23]]
  SQL (3.0ms)  DELETE FROM "groups" WHERE "groups"."id" = 23
 => #<Group id: 23, name: "groupie", created_at: "2013-03-18 15:29:42", updated_at: "2013-03-18 15:29:42", user_id: nil>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found the solution to the question. I actually wrote a code for an around_filter that messed up the destroy session for every controller:

```
  around_filter :clear_registration_id_on_destroy_session, only: :destroy


  def clear_registration_id_on_destroy_session
      is_filter_active = (controller_path == 'devise/sessions' && params[:action] == 'destroy')

      if is_filter_active && user_signed_in?
        if current_user.update_attribute(:device_platform, nil)
          logger.info "Updated device platform attributes to nil"
        end

        if current_user.update_attribute(:registration_id, nil)
          logger.info "Updated registration id attributes to nil"
        end

        yield 
      end
  end
```

The problem is that I didn't yield anything for any other controller other than devise:sessions#destroy.

So for those who are as forgetful as me, please remember to think about the other conditions when is_filter_active is not true.

```
  def clear_registration_id_on_destroy_session
      is_filter_active = (controller_path == 'devise/sessions' && params[:action] == 'destroy')

      if is_filter_active && user_signed_in?
        if current_user.update_attribute(:device_platform, nil)
          logger.info "Updated device platform attributes to nil"
        end

        if current_user.update_attribute(:registration_id, nil)
          logger.info "Updated registration id attributes to nil"
        end

        yield 
      else
        yield
      end
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like your delete link is just acting as a link to the `show` action, as the `method` option is not being picked up.

You need to have the appropriate javascript included in your application layout, as the delete link requires JS to use the correct HTTP method.

If you are using Rails >= 3.1 make sure you have the following in the header of the layout file you are using for rendering the page:

```
<%= javascript_include_tag :application %>
```

Also make sure you have the csrf_meta_tag in your layout:

```
<%= csrf_meta_tag %>
```

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the answer but I have already included what you had mentioned but it still does not work. I have updated the question to include my application layout